# Tumbleweed wording is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, wording, tumbleweed-badge

This may be too rare to matter, but...

The description for the Tumbleweed badge is:

> Asked a question with **no votes**, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week.

*(Emphasis mine)*

The question which awarded me the badge actually had two votes: one up and one down.

Should the wording of the badge be changed to:

> Asked a question with **zero score**, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week.

Or instead should the criteria be changed to match the existing description?

Comment: I'd guess the criteria is incorrect as a post that gets any votes would seem to be active enough to no justify the badge

Comment: I felt the same way, but it's so much easier to just change the wording :)

Comment: In case someone is wondering, according to [the timeline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/228526/timeline) of the question in question shows the votes occurred the day after the question was asked, and not closer to when the badge was awarded

Comment: There's a missing parenthesis I think, it should be "(no votes) and (no answers) and (no comments) and (low views for a week)". Anyway, if you have an upvote and a downvote, you have +3 rep and I don't think you need a tumble weed and it's a bug in my opinion...

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ "This didn't behave the way it's described, fix the behaviour" is what you're bringing up there; "This isn't described the way it behaves, describe it differently" is different though and the nature of this request. You're welcome to open the former!

Comment: @Jonathan, I offered both as possible solutions. Change the wording **or** change the criteria. I know changing the wording is easier, but agree changing the criteria is most correct

Comment: Ah,  that's true, I missed that last sentence.

Comment: [bug] and [feature-request] are reasonable choices for tags here. Either or both, doesn't terribly matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the description as suggested, to better match what the badge is actually awarded for - score 0.

With you in the next build.

Answer (score 11):

I was prompted by some speculation in comments to build a timeline:

- *2014-04-13 01:37Z: One week after the latest vote.*
- 2014-04-12 19:04Z: [Badge awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed?userid=248072)
- *2014-04-12 18:15Z: One week after asking.*
- 2014-04-06 02:55Z: [Question edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/228526/timeline), at which point it was at +1/-1.
- 2014-04-06 01:37Z: You get a downvote for this question. (from your [rep history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/248072/mhlester?tab=reputation))
- 2014-04-06 00:20Z: You get an upvote for this question. (also from your [rep history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/248072/mhlester?tab=reputation))
- 2014-04-05 18:15Z: [Question asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228526/152515).

The speculation was that perhaps you actually went a week with no answers, comments, or votes and low views *after* receiving your two votes, but that seems not to be the case.

You got your badge just 7 days over asking your question, and less than 7 days after the most recent vote on it. It's safe to say this badge really does only care about your question having a score of 0 after a week, so your wording change would be accurate.